# PowerShell, can't get LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell

I have this working, but need `LastWriteTime` and can't get it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "CYCLE" | Select-Object Path, Line, LastWriteTime
```

I get an empty column and zero Date-Time data

Answer (score 4):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s output objects, which are of type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo), only contain the input file *path* (string), no other metadata such as `LastWriteTime`.

To obtain it, use a [*calculated property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), combined with the [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable),
which allows you to reference the input file at hand in the calculated property's expression script block as a [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instance as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), whose `.LastWriteTime` property value you can return:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -PipelineVariable file | 
  Select-String -Pattern "CYCLE" | 
    Select-Object Path, 
                  Line, 
                  @{ 
                    Name='LastWriteTime'; 
                    Expression={ $file.LastWriteTime }
                  }
```

Note how the pipeline variable, `$file`, must be passed *without the leading `$`* (i.e. as `file`) as the `-PipelineVariable` argument . `-PipelineVariable` can be abbreviated to `-pv`.

Comment: Get-ChildItem emits a [System.IO.FileInfo]. How does Select-String know to work on the content of the file? Usually I have seen `Select-String` inside a `ForEach-Object` and using a `-Path $_` parameter. Also, how would you compare an contrast a `sigil` with an `icon`?

Comment: @lit, _sigil_ is just a fancy way of saying _symbol_, though its literal definition comes [from magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil) - I've removed the term to avoid confusion.

Comment: @lit, `Select-String` has custom logic for `FileInfo` input built in, which, regrettably, isn't currently (properly) documented.

Comment: @lit, I've asked for the docs to be amended in [GitHub docs issue #8278](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/8278), which has further details.

Comment: This is a great use of `Select-Object` and computed properties. Personally, I generally only use computed properties like this for adding new properties on the original object, as the `Select-Object` output has a resulting type of `Selected.Original.Type`. I feel building a custom object better fits the intent of creating a new object based on data from two or more distinct ones, preventing confusion to those inspecting its members (`LastWriteTime` is resultant of `gci`, not `Select-String`, after all). But, this is only stylistic preference and is not an invalid approach by any means.

Comment: I worded that poorly, I meant I generally only use computed properties when adding new properties based on data already present on the original object.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, yes, this use of a calculated property - deriving the calculated value not from the input object, but from a pipeline variable - is unusual, but I think it enables a concise solution that is still conceptually clear enough. Indeed, when the type name matters (which isn't typical), emitting a `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`  is needed (`([pscustomobject] @{ PSTypeName = 'MyType'; foo = 42 }).pstypenames[0]` works, but `(Get-Item / | Select-Object Name, @{ n = 'PSTypeName'; e = { 'MyType' } }).pstypenames[0]` doesn't).

Comment: @mklement0, many thanks for your explanation and efforts to get it properly documented. Using words like `sigil` is good. Words that are not used die.

Comment: My pleasure, @lit. I had heard _sigil_ many times, without having known it from any other context, and now that I've looked up the original meaning, I'm a bit puzzled (the coinage may have ben tongue-in-cheek, along the lines of "magic numbers" at the start of files). Given that it's a rare word, and many users aren't native English speakers, I wonder if _symbol_ will do.

Answer (score 3):

`LastWriteTime` is a property of [System.IO.FileSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-5.0), which is the base type of the items `Get-ChildItem` returns for the `Filesystem` provider (which is [System.IO.FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=net-5.0) for files). `Path` and `Line` are properties of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`, which contains information about the match, not the file you passed in. `Select-Object` operates on the information piped into it, which comes from the previous expression in the pipeline, your `Select-String` in this case.

You can't do this as a (well-written) one-liner if you want the file name, line match, and the last write time of the actual file to be returned. I recommend using an intermediary `PSCustomObject` for this and we can loop over the found files and matches individually:

```
# Use -File to only get file objects
$foundMatchesInFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
  
  # Assign $PSItem/$_ to $file since we will need it in the second loop
  $file = $_

  # Run Select-String on each found file
  $file | Select-String -Pattern CYCLE | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Path = $_.Path
      Line = $_.Line
      FileLastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime
    }
  }
}
```

> **Note:** I used a slightly altered name of `FileLastWriteTime` to exemplify that this comes from the returned *file* and not the match provided by `Select-String`, but you could use `LastWriteTime` if you wish to retain the original property name.

Now `$foundMatchesInFiles` will be a collection of files which have `CYCLE` occurring within them, the path of the file itself (as returned by `Select-String`), and the last write time of the file itself as was returned by the initial `Get-ChildItem`.

---

### Additional considerations

You could also use `Select-Object` and computed properties but IMO the above is a more concise approach when merging properties from *unrelated* objects together. While not a poor approach, `Select-Object` outputs data with a type containing the original object type name (e.g. `Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`). The code may work fine but can cause some confusion when others who may consume this object in the future inspect the output members. `LastWriteTime`, for example, belongs to `FileSystemInfo`, not `MatchInfo`. Another developer may not understand where the property came from at first if it has the `MatchInfo` type referenced. It is generally a better design to create a new object with the merged properties.

That said this is a minor issue which largely comes down to stylistic preference and whether this object might be consumed by others aside from you. I write modules and scripts that many other teams in my organization consume so this is a concern for me. It may not be for you. [@mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773154/584676) is an excellent example of how to use computed properties with `Select-Object` to achieve the same functional result as this answer.